# Identify stop codons

Tags: python, dna-sequence

I was trying to write some code that identifies stop codons in my sequence. I wrote the following code, but when I try it out, it stops after I type in my sequence when prompted. I am not sure why it doesn't go through. Thanks a lot!

```
dna=input("Please type your DNA sequence: ")

stopcodons=("TAG","TGA","TAA")
pos=0

while (pos+2)<(len(dna)):
    if dna[pos:pos+3] in stopcodons:
        type("Your sequence has a stop codon at %s position." %pos)
    else:
        pos=pos+3
```

Comment: Because you **only** increment `pos` in the `else` case.

Answer (score 0):

your loop is never going to end if you find a position because you do not increment pos.
Also, I'm not sure why you increment by 3 pos.

```
while (pos+2)<(len(dna)):
    if dna[pos:pos+3] in stopcodons:
        type("Your sequence has a stop codon at %s position." %pos)
    pos=pos+1
```

should work better

Comment: @No. Consider `ATGACA`. Start at position 0: No match. Skip three positions, another no match. No matching stop codons!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your program goes into an infinite loop once it has found a stop codon, is because **you instruct your program to only increment `pos` (and thus move the *cursor*) in the `else` case**: when you did not found a sequence.

You thus have to update the cursor every time:

```
while (pos+2)<(len(dna)):
    if dna[pos:pos+3] in stopcodons:
        print("Your sequence has a stop codon at %s position." %pos)
    pos=pos+3
```

(or even better: use `pos += 3` instead of `pos = pos + 3`).

You also have to use `print` instead of `type` since `type` simply obtains the type of an object.

Note that it is usually safer to use a `range(..)` in a `for` loop, like:

```
for pos in range(0,len(dna),3):
    if dna[pos:pos+3] in stopcodons:
        print("Your sequence has a stop codon at %s position." %pos)
```

Comment: Probably, you should encourage people to use the string utilities available to them, instead of rolling their own string matching algorithm (in this case, using a naive and inefficient one). Indeed, I suspect that just using `find` for each of the separate stop codon would be faster.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: note that the resulting index should be dividable by three. So it will still require some looping, since you can obtain a value like `'ATAGAA'`...

Comment: Why should it be divisible by three? You realize, DNA coding regions can overlap and be non-aligning...

Comment: Because DNA/RNA is translated by a *ribosome* in groups of three, and the ribosome (in the cells nucleaus) recognizes only groups of three.

Comment: I think you need to revisit your fundamentals of molecular biology. For example, ribosomes are generally not found in the nucleus, but can either be attached to the endoplasmic reticulum (making the so-called "rough" ER) or just free-floating in the cytoplasm.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_code#/media/File:RNA-codon.png) image seems to contradict that...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138048/discussion-between-juanpa-arrivillaga-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: Many thanks Willem! This makes sense. The way I had it before, after it finds a stop codon, it will go back and loop around itself because the "while statement" still holds true. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You almost **NEVER** want to use a counter, or index into arrays/strings directly in Python.

```
dna=input("Please type your DNA sequence: ")

stopcodons=("TAG","TGA","TAA")

for stopcodon in stopcodons:
    if stopcodon in dna:
        print("Your sequence has a stop codon at %s position" % dna.find(stopcodon))
```

The above is more "Pythonic" and helps to prevent numerous mistakes that are all too common in less advanced languages.

Comment: Thanks Eugene. This is elegant but not sure if I can use it to look for stop codons in a specific frame.